# How to instal Ubuntu on a macbook after HD upgrade?

Tags: installation, upgrade, macbook

I recently upgraded my hard drive to 1TB in my macbook (Model no A1342), after the upgrade my macbook turned on to a flashing folder with a question mark on it.

I did some research online on this problem and it turns out that I need to reinstall the operating system. Now I don't have my Mac OS Install DVD and my Applications Install DVD that came with the macbook since I let a friend borrow them sometimes last summer and he never returned them. According to apple I need these two disks to fix this problem,

I was wondering if there is anyway to install Ubuntu on my macbook without installing the mac os and if yes could someone walk me through the install?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ubuntu 13.10 Mac ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso). It is made to run on macs. Burn the iso to a dvd and install it on the mac. Press C during startup to boot from the dvd and install it from there. Please feel free to post again if you need more help.